# Format math equations in JTextPane while typing

Tags: java, swing, math, jtextpane

I am creating a program that involves typing mathematical equations such as polynomials from the user in a JTextPane. My problem is that I want the JTextPane to be able to format the equations typed by the user.

So as the user types their equations their inputs become formatted such as typing "^" would format the text as a raise to.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: That involves StyledDocument, AttributeSet and such. I think easier would be to provide icons such as already exist for **B** _I_: a toggleable `^` icon. Then you only have to deal with a _superscript character_ attribute. A bit of work. You could render HTML with `<sup>` and `<sub>`.